# How to create built-in indicator in Metatrader

Tags: mql4, metatrader4, mql5, mt4

I need to create custom indicator & add it as built-in indicator to 'Indicator/Trend' directory.
How can I do it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### First:

**Create** the <kbd>**`Custom Indicator`**</kbd> and then **code** its behaviour according to the **`MQL4`** syntax / processing logic.

### Next:

Use the GUI `Mouse.RightCLICK` or `Mouse.Drag&Drop` interactions to associate the compiled <kbd>`CustomIndicator`</kbd> with an <kbd>MT4.Graph</kbd> of your choice.

You might have already realised, that the [Navigator] panel displays user-defined indicators in a trailing section of the Terminal's Navigation Tree. AFAIK there is no direct way to specify, the less to enforce, in which other branch a new <kbd>`Custom Indicator`</kbd> should appear. Terminal simply puts 'em all to a root level, under other leaf-categories { Trend | Oscillators | Volumes | Bill Williams | Examples } and maintains nothing more complex then a simple alphabetical ordering. As the filesystem-level representation appears only for <kbd>`Examples`</kbd> and <kbd>`Custom Indicators`</kbd> there should your efforts go, if you strictly need to categorise your indicators in some specific manner.